# Статусы СМС (правила наименование, не программирование)

Tags: c#

Извините, если не в тему. 
Вопрос не по программированию, а по правилам наименования статусов смс - известно, что статусы СМС должны называться (одним) английским словом, например "**SENT**", "**ERROR**", "**CREATED**".

Вопрос:
Как таким же самым образом назвать следующие статусы:

> 1. ожидает доставки
> 2. передано оператору

Спасибо.

Comment: Я бы использовал SENT для "передано оператору" и Delivered для доставлено (т.е. то, что у вас сейчас SENT зовется). Не понятно, зачем нужен статус "ожидает доставки"? Если оно передано оператору и не доставлено, то оно ожидает доставку.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, вопрос закрыт

Comment: @Vlad преобразуйте свой комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю следующее:

1. Использовать статус Sent для обозначения состояния "передано оператору".
2. Использовать статус Delivered для обозначения состояния "доставлено абоненту"
3. Не добавлять статус "ожидает доставку", т.к. он по сути уже есть(sent - передано оператору. В этот момент абонент как раз ожидает доставку).